# How can I access model property inside viewmodel using asp-for?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, viewmodel, tag-helpers

I have this model

```
public partial class MtbWarehouse
{
    public int Idhwarehouse { get; set; }
    public string Namewh { get; set; }
}
```

I implement the model in this view model

```
public class WarehouseViewModel 
{
    public MtbWarehouse Warehouse { get; set; }
    public string ListAction { get; set; } = "Index";
}
```

And I am using WarehouseViewModel in view

```
@model ViewModel.warehouseviewmodel 
<input type="text" asp-for="Warehouse" class="form-control" placeholder="">
```

How can I access `Namewh` using `asp-for` because this asp-for thing is better than using

```
@Html.TextBoxFor()
```

Comment: What is `namewh`? Never heard of it before

Comment: namewh is property in model that i implement in warehouse viewmodel

Comment: where do you want to access it ? how ?

Comment: i want to acces it in view warehouse view. in past it using html.textbox now i don't know.

Comment: Have you tried `asp-for="Warehouse.Namewh"`? It also appears as though your @model doesn't match your class name, but I'm assuming that much works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are after rendering an input text element for `Namewh` property of the `Warehouse` property of your view model, you can use the dot notation to access a child properties' property. Like this

```
<form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">   
    <input type="text" asp-for="Warehouse.Namewh" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

This will generate an input text element with name `Warehouse.Namewh` and will render the value of that property if you set that from your GET action method.

VS Intellisense may still show this as invalid with red color. But when this code is executed, the tag helper will generate the correct input field with the value

Comment: it's is not like that. i want to access the warehouse in warehouseviewmodel in old way it use @html.textboxfor(m => m.warehouse.namewh) in new way i don't know

Comment: When you use `asp-for="Warehouse.Namewh" ` it produces the name attribute as `name="Warehouse.Namewh"`. Is there any way to make it generate `name="Namewh"`?